# Viewing hd location of installed certificates in firefox

Tags: firefox, security, certificate, digital-signature

I recently installed a digital id/certificate from verisign and was wondering if there is a way to view the certificate location on my computer. I installed it according to their instructions through firefox and can view it in firefox (options->options->advanced->encryption->view certificates). Is there anyway to find out the location of the certificate on my local HD? I am trying to use the digital certificate in outlook and thunderbird and need the location of certificate. Is this possible or should I just backup the certificate and use that location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exactly location of certificate on HD but you can `Backup` them to at your desired place and access them easily.

Just go to `Tools>Options>Advanced>Encryption>View Cerificate` and click on that button. Now `Certificate Manager` window will appear and select the certificate you want to make backup and click on `Backup` button and save the certificate at your desired place.

[image]

Comment: Exporting is indeed the best option. The "Backup" function exports to a PKCS#12 file, which all programs, including Outlook, can import. On the other hand, pointing Outlook directly to the internal store used by Firefox will not work at all, since the certificates are stored in a NSS database which Outlook cannot use.

Comment: But is it good to call the Backup to Export button?

Comment: Cool. I will export/back up the certificate

Comment: Is there anyway to determine the internal source location that firefox uses just for curiosity/my info and not to use it with my mail clients?

Comment: As noted early by grawity, mail clients like Outlook won't use FF's certstore.  If you want it to be ignored by your mail client, you'll want to post it as a separate question. Include the mail client in question and your OS/OS version.

Comment: I just want to know where the original certificate is located. Since I used firefox to install it that is the only place I can view the certificate. I know if I want to use outlook with it I have to use the backup function but I don't care about  using outlook. I just want to know where the original certificate is stored.

Comment: @Ben I have no idea about this where they store on HD because after asking your this question I tried to find the location but there is no certificate of the browser showing included in hidden files. So clearly I don't know the location and may be another expert may know this. I had been used only the `backup` way to see them.